# Search Engine using MVC: Pros and cons of using JSON and rendering client-side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am implementing a search engine for my project and have a requirement to display different types of search results, like images, videos and text depending upon user selection.
I am thinking of having separate viewmodels for each search type and returning a Json result back to the view. Then on client side, parse through the result and display result accordingly.

What are the pros and cons of using a JSON-based view rendering system?

Comment: I've updated your question to be something that I think is more amenable to this site.  Generally asking for advice is frowned upon.  I'm hoping that asking for pros/cons of a particular approach is better tolerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach you chose is quite good.

Definitely there are many questions which needs to be answered e.g. what if customer browser does not support JavaScript (i.e. JavaScript is disabled) - will you provide alternative rendering method or you assume all customers will have JS enabled (e.g. for Intranet applications you can make that assumptions).

If you check Google's search they have very similar approach - search results come as JSON response and build presentation in a page.

Answer (score 1):

Using a fully baked JSON solution is a reasonable choice, especially in light of the fact that you are building a search engine that likely does not need to be indexed itself. Using a javascript-only solution would limit the ability of (other) search engines to adequately index the site and, if this is important to you, is a less desirable approach.   Delivering as JSON offloads some processing onto the client and thus can make your server more performant as it can render the, much simpler, JSON rather than generate HTML.

The approach that I would take would be progressive enhancement.  Deliver the first page of results using a server-side view, then subsequent pages via AJAX - either as JSON results delivered and mark-up created client-side or as HTML rendered server-side and inserted into the proper spot in the DOM. If you choose JSON in this scenario, you need to realize that you'll be duplicating view rendering code in both the client and server.

You might want to look at using a framework like http://knockoutjs.com/ if you choose to go the full client-side approach.  This would allow you to use a client-side MVC approach.

Comment: I didn't quite get when you said - "Deliver the first page of results using a server-side view, then subsequent pages via AJAX - either as JSON results delivered and mark-up created client-side or as HTML rendered server-side and inserted into the proper spot in the DOM If you choose JSON in this scenario, you need to realize that you'll be duplicating view rendering code in both the client and server." How is the code getting duplicated in both client and server?

Comment: @annantDev well, you'd have your HTML in the view that first gets rendered with whatever code is needed to iterate over the first page of results. then, if you used JSON, you'd need to have javascript to take the JSON and build HTML from a template (or using the existing results on the page as a template). If you deliver HTML instead of JSON, then you can reuse the server-side view code to construct it and you only need to insert it on the client.

Comment: I want to choose both the answers as correct, as they both guided me in the right direction. However, site doesn't let me choose 2, so I'll go with the first response. Thank you both @tom and tvanfosson